# How is it possible that "-Wl,-rpath=" fails to find a library?

Tags: c

Basically I want to use a library in a custom dicrectory:

Compiler arguments:

```
gcc -o conftest -Wl,-rpath=/MYPATH/ssl/lib -O2 -Wno-system-headers  -I/MYPATH/ssl//include -I/MYPATH/ssl//include/openssl  -L/MYPATH/ssl//lib conftest.c -lssl  -lcrypto -lrt
```

Compiler error (one of many):

```
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `dlopen'
```

(This example is taken from a failed curl config.log file, but the question is of general nature)

I have double-checked that libssl.a and libcrypto.a exists in `/MYPATH/ssl/lib` and as seen above the `-Wl,rpath=` option is correctly set as compiler arguments.

How is it possible that gcc does not find the library, despite using "-Wl,rpath"? As far as I thought (so far), "-Wl,rpath" should never fail regardless of any environment variables (like LD_LIBRARY_PATH, etc.) or files.

Are there any environment variables that can cause "-Wl,-rpath=" to fail?

Comment: Because you need to link with the `dl` library for `dlopen`. Also, the error posted is a linker error, using `-Wl,rpath` sets the *run-time* path while `-L` sets the link-time path. Furthermore, if you link with static libraries, you need to add all the libraries they depend on, as a static library aren't self-contained.

Comment: Great comment, do you think that it is possible that the problem is caused by a badly-compiled openssl library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comment from Joachim, the correct answer seems to be:

-Wl,rpath= sets the runtime path
-L sets the linking path

and to answer the question:

No, -Wl,rpath cannot be negatively influenced by system variables.